# Ruby regex for domain validation

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I'm looking for a regex to validate my user's chosen domain, I.E. `http://mysite.com/userdomain`.

All I'm concerned with is that it allows the right characters.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing. You're talking about the domain, which is the mysite.com part; but you've also written userdomain as the first level folder - which would seem to indicate that you might be talking about valid url folder names. Which is it? Do you need to validate "mysite.com", "mysite.com/userdomain", or "userdomain" alone?

Comment: For this check to be of any use in the real world you'll eventually want to know if the domain actually exists. While it's relatively easy to see if the domain is syntactically correct, that won't tell you what you really need to know, which is whether it is usable and alive. And, your best bet to do that is to actually ping it or try to connect, and, to do that you'll probably want to honor the actual scheme, such as ftp or http. So, at that point, it probably makes even more sense to just use URI or Addressable::URI as @Bert Goethals suggested. I prefer Addressable::URI myself.

Comment: I'm talking about the folder name here

Answer (score 5):

Well, a regex will help you a long way, but you might want to consider just parsing the URL.

```
def validate_url(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.class != URI::HTTP
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```

Alternatively Addressable::URI could be used instead of URI (suggested by @abe-voelker)

(source: http://actsasblog.wordpress.com/2006/10/16/url-validation-in-rubyrails/)

Comment: thanks,  but it's not actually the full url that I need to validate,  just the user's chosen domain

Comment: If going this route, may I suggest using Addressable::URI instead, as it has better support for the RFC specs and internationalization.

Comment: +1 for parsing using an established library, and... oh, I can't +1 again for suggesting Addressable::URI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) to test your Regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Just head over to [Regex Lib](http://regexlib.com/%28A%286Tt5qV91gGX4eY9P8nhCV3m3J1udPc3NFnO8QGc8rtOksqXWT2JJCT1zQsBQ0PfPAoxYuOhcKsX4x9wxGlPc73qq8uEiAoHskRsWXagvq2yW5cRVPEvBO40wA1jw9SbeD2fxFOH1u3qdextAFkuph4wXGNcLB6CeIm5GuD_JP7MzNtiY171K1AXB0ohcXm1E0%29%29/Search.aspx?k=domain&c=2&m=5&ps=20) and pick one you like (the link already points to a search for the type of regular expression you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to figure out whether the user is giving you a name that is valid as a folder in a url? (`CGI.escape(some_folder_name) != some_folder_name` would probably get you where you need for that.)

---

Or are you looking for `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(some_url_string))`?

That generates a regexp which matches any instance of `some_url_string`.

Used like so:

```
user.domain = "http://mysite.com/userdomain" # or "mysite.com/userdomain"
incoming_domain = "http://mysite.com/userdomain/a_post"
users_domain_regexp = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(user.domain))
if incoming_domain =~ users_domain_regexp
   puts "By George, we've done it!"
else
   puts "I'm sorry, but we're prejudiced against that url"
end
#=> "By George, we've done it!"
```

Comment: Why use a regex match? A sub-string match would be just as useful and less hassle. `!!incoming_domain[user.domain]` will give a true/false.

Comment: I'm fairly certain he's actually talking about the folder 'userdomain', rather than an actual domain name; and he wants to make sure that users are selecting names for that folder that won't break in urls.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm asking